# Is there any way to get signature algorithm of client certificate during mutual TLS authentication in Nginx?

Tags: ssl, nginx, ssl-certificate, signature, mutual-authentication

I have configured mutual TLS authentication follow http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html reference. In my business, I need to judge whether the signature algorithm of the client certificate is using SHA-256 or not. I see Nginx has some embedded variables but seems none can meet my requirement. Any possibility here? Thanks.